# AngularJS - Expandable rows not working with ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, video.js

I have hard-coded two expandable rows which work fine. However, when I try to introduce ng-repeat the rows will no longer expand.

Working version: https://jsbin.com/tiwufiz/3/edit?html,js,console,output

ng-repeat version: https://jsbin.com/tiwufiz/5/edit?html,js,console,output

In the ng-repeat version all I have done is delete the second row, introduced ng-repeat and done ng-binding on the title...

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="tut in demo.tutorials">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <button class="collapsible">{{tut.title}}</button>
        <div class="content">
                <video class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="false" width="640" height="264"
                style="display:block; margin: 0 auto">
                <source src="resources/comercial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <p class="vjs-no-js">
                    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                    <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                </p>
            </video>
            <div class="mt10 mb10">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

I wrapped the for loop inside a $timeout (zero secs)